# Lucene Text highlighting in Arabic language

Tags: lucene

I have a lucene 8+ project, dealing with various languages including arabic.

The existing code for highlighting search hits works quite well, except in arabic, as the matches and text fraqments are not put together in a right to left manner.

Is there a way to configure the hightlighter to be aware and able to do so?

Kind regards